# Variable returning to Null?

Tags: c, sockets, while-loop, fork

I'm trying to practice my socket programming by printing multiple things to the same file based on the first string sent. I found out that my char pointers kept getting nullified after their run so the name that was first sent is no longer stored. What's going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

char* doprocessing (char *fnptr) {
    fnptr = "filename.txt";
    return fnptr;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int count=0, pid;
    char *fnptr = NULL;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1){

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            close(sockfd);
            printf("Pid is 0\n");
            fnptr = doprocessing(fnptr);
            printf("Fnptr is %s\n", fnptr);
            exit(0);
        }

        else {
            printf("Fnptr in else is %s\n", fnptr);
            close(newsockfd);
        }
        printf("fnptr outside of else is %s\n", fnptr);

    }

}
```

---

Output

```
Fnptr in else is (null) //Expected
fnptr outside of else is (null) //Expected
Pid is 0 //Start of processing
Fnptr is filename.txt //Goal
Fnptr in else is (null) //Where'd it go?
fnptr outside of else is (null) //Not good :(
```

Comment: You know that `fork` creates a new process, and processes have their own address spaces? (= their own copies of memory)

Comment: TIL. So every time the process forks off, the variable is poofed into existence? Any way to keep track of it?

Comment: No, the forked process has its own memory. The assignment to `fnptr` in your `if(pid == 0)` branch has absolutely no effect on the parent process, so it's still null there. You need to use some sort of inter-process communication (simplest here would be `pipe`)

Comment: There is a way and it's called *shared memory* or *inter process communication* (**IPC**). Read more about them on Google. You could also use pipes to communicate inter process. But, my guess is that you do not actually want to use a new entire process to handle that request, but rather a new **thread**. In this way, your `fnptr` will be *naturally* shared among the two entities.

Comment: Is "poofed" a politically correct word these days?

Comment: Yes @EdHeal. Thanks guys, I was able to use this guide http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html#SECTION00722000000000000000 to solve my issue. Piping does in fact work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questionably sound, but working code! Using the guide found here: [TLDP Man Page - Creating Pipes in C](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html#SECTION00722000000000000000), I was able to implement piping the char pointer in order to keep track of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

char* doprocessing (char *fnptr) {
    fnptr = "filename.txt";
    return fnptr;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int count=0, pid, fd[2], nbytes;
    char *fnptr = NULL, readbuffer[80];

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5002;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    pipe(fd);

    while(1){

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            close(sockfd);
            printf("Pid is 0\n");
            fnptr = doprocessing(fnptr);
            printf("Fnptr is %s\n", fnptr);
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], fnptr, (strlen(fnptr)+1));
            exit(0);
        }

        else {
            close(fd[1]);
            nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            fnptr = readbuffer;
            printf("Fnptr in else is %s\n", fnptr);
            close(newsockfd);
        }
        printf("fnptr outside of else is %s\n", fnptr);

    }

}
```